# Is the Zarr's Cannon/Barrage subject to shotgun status calculations?

Tags: warframe

So if you don't know how status works with shotguns, here's the quick rundown:

- At <100% status pre-MS (multishot), status chance of each pellet is calculated as

  - (status % / # of pellets)
- At 100% status pre-MS, status chance of each pellet is 100%, no matter how many pellets are fired.
- With any other weapon class, as you long as you hit 100% status you will proc status on any shot, regardless of multishot.

The Zarr however is classified as an Assault Rifle (as funny as that sounds).  Unfortunately, for the life of me, I can't figure out if this thing works off of normal status calculations for rifle weapons or is subject to shotgun calculations, because when testing it in the Simulacrum, it is inconsistent at giving status procs, both in Cannon mode and Barrage mode.

In Barrage mode, the gun fires in a spread shot, similar to a shotgun. In Cannon mode, it lobs a single bomb until it hits terrain, then splits into a multitude of smaller bombs afterwards.

My question is: in both Barrage and Cannon mode, are the extra explosives/shots factoring in status via Shotguns, or not?

For those asking what my mod setup is, I'm running 4x dual status mods to achieve 100% status pre MS.